# NodeJS Mongoose Passport local strategy query Mongodb gives error,

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport-local, passport.js

I have a Passport local strategy try to query a user in mongodb:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done){
      console.log("username and password is >>>>>", username, password);
      var findOne = Q.nbind(User.findOne, User);
      findOne({"username": username})
      .then(function(user){
        console.log("inside findone user>>>>>", err, user);

        if (!user) {
          return done( null, false, {messge: 'This user is not registered.'});
        }

        if (!user.comparePasswords(password)){
          return done(null, false, {message: 'This password is not correct'});
        }

        return done(null, user);
      })
      .fail(function(err){
        console.log("failed at here");
        return done(null, false, {message: "Server have difficulty"});
      })
    }
  ));
```

"failed at here" is printed, which means there's error accessing mongodb. However, I write the very similar function in my signup function, and every thing works fine:

```
exports.signup = function(req, res, next){
  console.log("hit the signup function");
  var findOne = Q.nbind(User.findOne, User);
  findOne({username: req.body.username})
  .then(function(user){
    console.log("user from query is >>>>>", user);
    if (!user){
      // user doesn't exist, create a new one\
      var create = Q.nbind(User.create, User);
      var newUser = {username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password};
      return create(newUser);
    } else {
      // user already exist, redirect to sign in page
      res.send(409, 'already exist');
      //res.redirect('/signin');
    }
  })
  .then(function(user){
    res.json(200,user);
  })
  .fail(function(err){
    //next(err);
    console.log("error is >>>>", err);
    res.redirect('/signin');
  })
};
```

I have created a user through signup. so it will give me 409 when i try to sign up with the same user. However, when I try to sign in with that user, the passport local strategy reports error accessing mongodb. Any thoughts? 
You are welcome to take a look at the repo: https://github.com/7seven7lst/chatterApp
The passport config can be found in: https://github.com/7seven7lst/chatterApp/blob/master/lib/routes.js
and the signup can be found in: 
https://github.com/7seven7lst/chatterApp/blob/master/lib/controllers/user.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.then(function(user){
  console.log("inside findone user>>>>>", err, user);
```

The error is being thrown because that `err` isn't defined.

If you log the actual error that the `fail` function:

```
.fail(function(err){
  console.log("failed at here", err);
  return done(null, false, {message: "Server have difficulty"});
})
```

you will see:

```
ReferenceError: err is not defined
    at /Users/dting/chatterApp/lib/routes.js:16:49
```